# Reactjs , Source Array becomes blank on component reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Attached sample code for two files: 
dummyService.js
Home.jsx

I am surprised about the console.log in service.js, how that becomes bank.[image]

Comment: Hey Susanta! Just a heads up - try not to post your code as an image and instead copy it here so that it is easily copied and tinkered about. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Sure, will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array `splice` method modifies array in-place. Easiest fix in your case is to create a shallow copy: `const arrCopy = [...arr]`;

Comment: Thnak you got it.